# Parsing *.scn files from Bio Rad Image Lab in python

Tags: python, image, image-processing, medical-imaging

Im using Bio-Rad Image Lab software (https://www.bio-rad.com/en-il/product/image-lab-software?ID=KRE6P5E8Z) to scan biochemical reactions slides.
The software can save mutiple-images  in one action as *.scn files.

I want to convert the *.scn files to *.tiff by myself using Python.
ImageJ can open these *.scn files.
Yet, I could not open these files using either slideio or tifffile (python packages) and of course opencv also failes.

For example, when using **tifffile**:

```
import tifffile

path = 'img.scn'
img = tifffile.imread(path)
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception has occurred: TiffFileError
not a TIFF file b'MIME'
KeyError: b'MI'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  File "/mnt/c/analysis/dev_analysis/2022_12_12_scn_extract/scn2tiff.py", line 9, in <module>
    img = tifffile.imread(path)
tifffile.tifffile.TiffFileError: not a TIFF file b'MIME'
```

When using **slideio**:

```
import slideio

path = 'img.scn'
slide = slideio.open_slide(path, "SCN")
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception has occurred: RuntimeError
SCNImageDriver: Cannot open file:img.scn
  File "/mnt/c/analysis/dev_analysis/2022_12_12_scn_extract/scn2tiff.py", line 6, in <module>
    slide = slideio.open_slide(path, "SCN")
RuntimeError: SCNImageDriver: Cannot open file:img.scn
```

Comment: welcome. [tour], [ask], [mre]. MRE needs to include sample data file. -- if you just need to convert, look into **imagemagick** -- **bug reports** for slideio go there: https://github.com/Booritas/slideio/issues

Comment: Bio-Rad SCN is different from the TIFF based Leica SCN slide format. [Bio-Formats](https://docs.openmicroscopy.org/bio-formats/6.11.1/formats/bio-rad-scn.html) should be able to open it.

Comment: Thanks. Bio-Formats indeed solve it: https://docs.openmicroscopy.org/bio-formats/6.11.1/developers/python-dev.html

I found the easiest solution to use AICSImageIO implementation of Bio-Formats package as described here under QuickStart: (https://allencellmodeling.github.io/aicsimageio/)